# in CodeIgniter form_validation not working

Tags: codeigniter, validation

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url().'login/index'; ?>" method="post" name="loginForm" id="loginForm">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off">  
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

****Controller****

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()

    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation- 
          >set_rules('username','username','required');
        $this->form_validation- 
                   >set_rules('password','Password','required');
    
         if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
            $this->load->view('admin/login');
        }
        else{
            echo"Form validation Successfully";
        }
        
    
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: if the form field is blank  then form should not be submitted

Comment: What should happen in that case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `base_url()` without adding this library

```
// need this to use base_url() in the template.php
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
```

try with this line again